# Using QTBodiniPoster font

Tags: fonts

I wish to use to `QTBodiniPoster font` for the `title` in my document and the rest of the document in `default LaTeX font`. I use:

```
\setmainfont{QTBodiniPoster}
```

in the preamble and then for rest of the text switch to `cmr` font using command `\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont`. The text changes to the default computer roman font, but I am `unable to italicize` the `cmr` font now. Anyone kindly help and suggest.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setmainfont{QTBodiniPoster}

\begin{document}

\textit{\LARGE{Feynman's Preface}}
\normalsize
\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont
\textit{\underline{Hello}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `{\fontspec{QTBodiniPoster} balabala}` without having to change the basic font.

Answer (score 2):

Define a special command for the special font.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\TITLEFONT}{Futura}%{QTBodiniPoster}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\TITLEFONT\itshape\LARGE
Feynman's Preface
\end{center}

This text uses Latin Modern; \textit{Hello}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `fontenc` and `lmodern` should not be used along with `fontspec`.

I used a distinctive font I have instead of the one you want (that I don't have).